# Adding layer to group in layers panel using PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, group-layer

I am trying to add a group to the layer panel, then place a vector layer (vectorLayer) into this group from a python script. The code I am using is:

```
groupName="test group"
root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()
group = root.addGroup(groupName)

group.insertChildNode(-1, QgsLayerTreeLayer(vectorLayer))
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(vectorLayer,True)
```

My issue is that this code always adds two copies of the vector layer. One of which will be in the group, the other is outside the group.

[image]

However, when I change the code to the following with the intent of not adding a second layer, the layer inside the group becomes '(?)'.

```
groupName="test group"
root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()
group = root.addGroup(groupName)

group.insertChildNode(-1, QgsLayerTreeLayer(vectorLayer))
# QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(vectorLayer,True)
```

[image]

Does this mean the layer inside the group is just a pointer to the layer outside the group?

How do I add a layer to a group without the duplicate layer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to make a clone of the layer and then move it and remove the original layer, try:

```
groupName="test group"
root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()
group = root.addGroup(groupName)
vlayer = QgsVectorLayer("C:/Temp/myShp.shp", "shpName","ogr")
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(vlayer)
root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()
layer = root.findLayer(vlayer.id())
clone = layer.clone()
group.insertChildNode(0, clone)
root.removeChildNode(layer)
```

Comment: Important note for QGIS 3.x users: QgsMapLaye Registry is extinct!
Use QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(vlayer) instead.

Comment: You probably want to use `layer.parent().removeChildNode(layer)` instead on the last line, then it will also work if a group is selected while the new layer is inserted

Answer (score 17):

Use addMapLayer(layer,**False**), which will add a layer without showing it

```
memlay = QgsVectorLayer("Point","myLayer", "memory")
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(memlay, False)    #False is the key
sgroup.addLayer(memlay)
```

Then you can simply add it to an existing group without cloning etc.

Answer (score 3):

```
groupName ="test group"
root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()
group = root.addGroup(groupName)
vlayer = QgsVectorLayer("C:/Temp/myShp.shp", "shpName","ogr")
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(vlayer)
group.insertChildNode(1, QgsLayerTreeLayer(vlayer))
```

Comment: Feel free to expand your answer by explaining, what you did and how it works, in order to make it easier understandable.