# Save QGIS project to PostgreSQL/PostGIS database using PyQGIS

Tags: postgis, pyqgis, postgresql, qgis-3, pyqgis-3

I'm currently working on some code to automate the creation of a QGIS project from tables in a PostgreSQL DB. For info I'm working in QGIS 3.4.

I'm almost there, but I'm stuck on one thing

- How do I save the project back into postgreSQL?

The code I've put together so far:

```py
# CONNEXION 
# This works fine

    uri = QgsDataSourceUri()
    DB = "MCD_1"
    user = "user1"
    MP = "XXXX"
    host = "XXX.XXX.XX.XXX"
    port = "XXXX"
    schema = "XXXX"

    uri.setConnection(host, port, DB, user, MP)

# OUTPUT FOLDER
# Here I define the ouput options - saving to local works ok but I'm not sure how to modify the 'PG_OUTPUT' to save into the DB

    LOC_OUTPUT = 'C:/Users/user1/Docs/SIG/test_output/loc_ouput.qgz'
    PG_OUTPUT = 'uri.setConnection(host, port, DB, user, MP)/TEST.qgz'  

# LOAD LAYERS
# works ok

    uri.setDataSource(schema, "DB_table_A", "geom")
    layer = QgsVectorLayer(uri.uri(False), "SIG_table_A", "postgres")
    QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer)

    uri.setDataSource(schema, "DB_view_A", "geom","", cb_PrimaryKey)
    layer = QgsVectorLayer(uri.uri(False), "SIG_view_A", "postgres")
    QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer)

# CREATE AND PLACE LAYERS IN GROUPS
# works ok

    root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()

    Group_1="Tables"
    group = root.addGroup(Group_1)

    table_1 = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("SIG_table_A")[0]
    root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()
    layer = root.findLayer(table_1.id())
    clone = layer.clone()
    group.insertChildNode(0, clone)
    root.removeChildNode(layer)


    Group_2="Views"
    group = root.addGroup(Group_2)

    view_1 = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("SIG_view_A")[0]
    root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()
    layer = root.findLayer(view_1.id())
    clone = layer.clone()
    group.insertChildNode(0, clone)
    root.removeChildNode(layer)

## SAVING PROJECT
# Here I just modify the variable in project.write() between PG_OUTPUT and  LOC_OUTPUT - to save locally or in the DB.

    project = QgsProject.instance()
    project.write(PG_OUTPUT)
```

sources:

https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/pdf/en/QGIS-3.4-PyQGISDeveloperCookbook-en.pdf

Creating Proj and layers:

[QGIS Python script for creating project file](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/130117/qgis-python-script-for-creating-project-file)

https://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=grouping+layers+pyqgis

[Grouping layers using PyQGIS makes them not visible on canvas?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/309557/grouping-layers-using-pyqgis-makes-them-not-visible-on-canvas)

[Adding layer to group in layers panel using PyQGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/290938/adding-layer-to-group-in-layers-panel-using-pyqgis)

Comment: QGIS 3.2 have a new option for save projects to  postgres  http://www.bostongis.com/blog/index.php?/archives/271-New-in-QGIS-3.2-Save-Project-to-PostgreSQL.html

Comment: Yes, that's basically what I'm trying to do - but through the python console :)

Comment: you need change settings value then.I can post an answer but I have not tried it if you want

Comment: try using `settings = QgsSettings()
baseKey = "/PostgreSQL/connections/" + connName;
settings.setValue( baseKey + "/projectsInDatabase", True )` ,based on core code  https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/src/providers/postgres/qgspgnewconnection.cpp#L75

Comment: Make sure you have at least PostGreSQL 9.4.  It won't work with older versions. https://issues.qgis.org/issues/21148

Comment: cheers for the replies - I still haven't worked it out yet - the core code is a bit beyond me (I'm still learning python)  - otherwise I'm running postgresql 11 (so it should be ok)

Answer (score 7):

You're very close. The only issue I see with your code is the `PG_OUTPUT` variable, which should actually be a URI like this:

```
uri = 'postgresql://user:pass@localhost:5432?dbname=my_db&schema=my_schema&project=my_project'
```

If you have the URI in that way, you can just call:

```
QgsProject.instance().write(uri)
```

And now your project will be stored in your DB.

---

Related:

- [Loading QGIS project from database using PyQGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/354593/load-qgis-project-from-database-using-pyqgis)
- [Deleting QGIS project stored in PostgreSQL using PyQGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/415056/deleting-qgis-project-stored-in-postgresql-using-pyqgis/415060#415060)