# Loading QGIS project from database using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, postgresql, qgis-plugins, geopackage

I am trying to open a QGIS project that is saved to the database (`Project -> Save to -> PostgreSQL`) by means of Python script.

I find a similar way to open project which is saved to the desktop using `QgsProject.instance().read(filename)`.

Can anyone guide me a similar way to open from database?

Comment: In https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.0/core/Project/QgsProject.html#qgis.core.QgsProject.read I am not able to find any relevant references to postgresql, so it may look as if it is not directly possible through python, but there are smart people around here, somebody may know something...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can load a project from a database storage (e.g., PostgreSQL or GeoPackage) in this way:

```
QgsProject.instance().read(uri)
```

Where `uri` is the file name of the project, which you could get from:

```
QgsProject.instance().fileName()
```

Since we are dealing with projects stored in databases, the file name is actually a `uri`.

---

**Sample `uri`s:**

- Project in a PostgreSQL database:

  ```
  'postgresql://user:password@localhost:5432?sslmode=disable&dbname=my_db&schema=my_schem&project=my_pg_project'
  ```
- Project in a GeoPackage database:

  ```
  'geopackage:/path/to/my_db.gpkg?projectName=my_gpgk_project'
  ```

---

Related:

- [Save QGIS project to PostgreSQL/PostGIS database using PyQGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/320934/save-qgis-project-to-postgresql-postgis-database-using-pyqgis/354621#354621)
- [Save QGIS project to GeoPackage using PyQGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/368285/save-qgis-project-to-geopackage-using-pyqgis/368288#368288)
- [Deleting QGIS project stored in PostgreSQL using PyQGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/415056/deleting-qgis-project-stored-in-postgresql-using-pyqgis/415060#415060)