# Save QGIS project to GeoPackage using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, geopackage

How it is possible save qgis project to GeoPackage in PyQGIS?

[image]

the image is user interface but I need in code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to construct a URI like this:

```
uri = 'geopackage:/path/to/db.gpkg?projectName=my_gpgk_project'
```

And then use it to save the project, in this way:

```
QgsProject.instance().write(uri)
```

Comment: Thanks that's worked, and do you have any idea where can I found documentation about this ?

Comment: Actually, not. But, GIS.SE is also a source of documentation. In fact, many answers provided here are later copied to official documentation sources. Of course, you always have the source code available, which, when programming, may be seen as the best documentation source (think about code comments and unit tests) at all.