# Can I start QGIS with a project from a GeoPackage?

Tags: qgis, geopackage

I can save a QGIS project within a GeoPackage, which is nice since it can include the data too. But can I start QGIS (from the command line, or otherwise on GUI systems) such that it gets the project from the GeoPackage?

`qgis project.gpkg` loads the layers, not the project (but includes the project database table as a non-geometry attribute table). `qgis -p project.gpkg` gives me a `"Unable to open /home/user/project.gpkg"` error. I can't see any other option or any other way of doing it, or any help via a google search.

If there isn't a way then I might distribute my project+data as separate `.qgz` and `.gpkg` files so the user can launch the `.qgz` file and get straight into it. I was wondering if there was a single file solution.

Am on QGIS 3.26.1, solutions for this or newer would be great.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the following syntax:

```
qgis -p geopackage:your.gpkg?projectName=your_project
```

I don't know where this is documented, I saw it in my recent projects list when opening QGIS:
[image]

But there's also references to this syntax on this site:

- [Save QGIS project to GeoPackage using PyQGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/368288/2856)
- [Loading QGIS project from database using PyQGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/354615/2856)