# Deleting QGIS project stored in PostgreSQL using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, postgresql, qgs

I would like to delete a .qgs project stored in PostgreSQL using PyQGIS.
This SQL code does the job into pgAdmin :

```
DELETE FROM test2.qgis_projects WHERE name = 'Project_name';
```

My attempt which doesn't work in PyQGIS is :

```
from PyQt5.QtSql import *
uri = QgsDataSourceUri()
uri.setConnection("localhost", "5432", "BDtest", "postgres", "password")

db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("BDtest");
db.setHostName(uri.host())
db.setDatabaseName(uri.database())
db.setPort(int(uri.port()))
db.setUserName(uri.username())
db.setPassword(uri.password())
db.open()
query = db.exec_("""DELETE FROM test2.qgis_projects WHERE name = 'Project_name';""")
query.next()
query.value(0)
print(query)
```

This last code doesn't work in PyQGIS, could someone correct it?

I think it misses uri.setDataSource() but I do not know how to use it, because the data I need to delete is a qgis_project (there is no geometry).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The recommended way of removing a QGIS project stored in a database is this:

1. **Build a proper `uri`**

   For PostgreSQL, something like:

   ```
   'postgresql://user:password@localhost:5432?sslmode=disable&dbname=my_db&schema=my_schema&project=my_pg_project'
   ```

   Note the `project=my_pg_project` at the end of the `uri`.
2. **Get the corresponding project storage object**

   ```
   storage = QgsApplication.projectStorageRegistry().projectStorageFromUri(uri)
   ```
3. **Remove the project**

   ```
    storage.removeProject(uri)
   ```

---

Related:

- [How to load a QGIS project from a database](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/354593/load-qgis-project-from-database-using-pyqgis).
- [How to save a QGIS project to a database](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/320934/save-qgis-project-to-postgresql-postgis-database-using-pyqgis/354621#354621).