# Geometry of layer disappears when creating scratch/memory layer with script

Tags: pyqgis, memory-layer

I'm trying to write a Python script (QGis 3.4.9) to create a group of scratch-layers (polygon, line and point). When it is inside the function the layer is created as it should, but when the function is done the geometry (and anything else it seems) is gone. The layer is there but no geometry. I'm clearly missing something?

```
def scratch_group():
    isthere = False
    sgroupname = "Scratch_group"
    root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()
    for child in root.children():
      if isinstance(child, QgsLayerTreeGroup):
        if child.name().upper() == sgroupname.upper():
            isthere = True
            print("- group: " + child.name() + " already there")

if not isthere:
    root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()
    sgroup = root.addGroup(sgroupname)

    stiep = "point"
    slayerp= QgsVectorLayer(stiep, "Scratch_point",  "memory")
    sgroup.insertChildNode(0, QgsLayerTreeLayer(slayerp))
    slayerp.startEditing()

QMessageBox.information(iface.mainWindow(),"Check","Geometry",QMessageBox.Ok)
return()
#---main---    
scratch_group()    
QMessageBox.information(iface.mainWindow(),"Check","If Geometry is gone",QMessageBox.Ok)
```

EDIT:
In the meantime i stumbled on [Adding layer to group in layers panel using PyQGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/290938/adding-layer-to-group-in-layers-panel-using-pyqgis)
You have to create a clone of the layer put it in place and remove the original.
That partially solved it:

```
def create_memlayer_ingroup(stiep, sname, sgroup):
    vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(stiep, sname,"memory")
    QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(vlayer)
    root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()
    ilayer = root.findLayer(vlayer.id())
    clone = ilayer.clone()
    sgroup.insertChildNode(0, clone)
    print(ilayer)
    root.removeChildNode(ilayer)

def create_sgroup(gname):
    rt = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()
    return(rt.addGroup(gname))

memgroup = create_sgroup("Scratch_group2")
create_memlayer_ingroup("Polygon", "Scratch_Polygon", memgroup)
create_memlayer_ingroup("Linestring", "Scratch_line", memgroup)
create_memlayer_ingroup("Point", "Scratch_point", memgroup)
```

This works when the group is not placed at the top of the tree. When it is at top (if no other layer is opened), the second and third memlayer is opened twice within the group. So not perfect yet...

Answer (score 2):

Finally I found the answer in [Add layer to a QGIS group using Python](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/75384/add-layer-to-a-qgis-group-using-python) from Germán Carrillo (many thanks). Thankfully you don't have to clone etc your layers which results in strange behaviour.

```
def create_slayer(tiep, lname, sgroup):
    memlay = QgsVectorLayer(tiep,lname, "memory")
    QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(memlay, False)    #False was the key
    sgroup.addLayer(memlay) 

def create_sgroup(gpos,gname):
    isthere = False      #check if group already exists
    rt = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()
    for child in rt.children():
        if isinstance(child, QgsLayerTreeGroup):   
           if child.name().upper() == gname.upper():    
               isthere = True

    if not isthere:      #if group not exists, create one
        memgroup = rt.insertGroup(gpos, gname)
        create_slayer("Point","Scratch_point",memgroup)
        create_slayer("Linestring","Scratch_line",memgroup)
        create_slayer("Polygon","Scratch_polygon",memgroup)

#---Main-----
create_sgroup(0,"Scratch_group")
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a workaround to add a layer in a group. You need to add to the layer tree and then move it in your chosen group.